# VS Code - Use prettier for specific projects and default formatting for others

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

I work on multiple Projects (Javascript - React Native). Some use the default formatting that comes with VS Code out of the box and some use prettier.
I now want to set up VS Code, so when i save a file it applies prettier, when prettier is used in the project, else use the default styling format.
I have installed the prettier extension and have set `"prettier.requireConfig": true` in the settings, so that it only applies in projects with a `.prettierrc` file.
So right now the formatting works in the prettier projects as expected, but when i save in other projects no formatting is applied at all.
This is what i added in vs codes settings.json:

```
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "[javascript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "prettier.requireConfig": true,
```

When i disable prettier and remove the defaultFormatter part, it will no longer apply prettier and use the vs code default style in all projects again.

So my question is, how can i set up vs code, so that i can use prettier properly in Projects that use it and when i have to do work in another Project i still have some basic formatting, but i don't reformat the whole file when i save.

Comment: save the prettier settings in the file `.vscode/settings.json` of the project/workspsace

Comment: That would require setting it for all prettier projects individually. I hoped for a solution that would work once for all (including future) projects, though i guess for now it's good enough